# How to get json nested in double square brackets?

Tags: php, json, regex, preg-match-all

Here is my sample:

```
dummy json: {json here: "asdas"}
[[table
  {json here: "asdas"}
]]
[[pre 
  {json here: "asdasx"}
]]
[[text {json here: "red"} ]]
```

and I want output like below:

```
{json here: "asdas"}
{json here: "asdasx"}
{json here: "red"}
```

**UPDATE** the json strings may contain curly brackets.

I just want to get all of the json strings, but I keep failing.
I've tried using `#\[\[(table|pre|text).+({.*?}).+\]\]#s` but I got the following output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(126) "[[table
      {json here: "asdas"}
    ]]
    [[pre 
      {json here: "asdasx"}
    ]]
    [[text {json here: "red"} ]]"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "table"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "{json here: "red"}"
  }
}
```

and btw I'm using php syntax `preg_match_all` to do above test.

Comment: [[table
  {json here: "asdas"}
]]  what is this . is this a string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your code working by altering your regex to this:

```
\[\[(?:table|pre|text)\s*(\{.*?\})\s*\]\]
```

Note carefully that brackets need to be escaped if you intend for them to be literal; you weren't doing this in the regex you showed us.

**Code:**

```
$userinfo = "[[table  {json here: \"asdas\"}]] [[pre {json here: \"asdasx\"}]] [[text {json here: \"red\"} ]]";
preg_match_all ("/\[\[(?:table|pre|text)\s*(\{.*?\})\s*\]\]/", $userinfo, $pat_array);
print $pat_array[1][0]." <br> ".$pat_array[1][1]." <br> ".$pat_array[1][2];
```

**Output:**

```
{json here: "asdas"} <br> {json here: "asdasx"} <br> {json here: "red"}
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: btw what's `?:` ?

Comment: The `?:` tells the regex engine _not_ to capture that group.  You don't want to capture `(table|pre|text)` so we can write is as `(?:table|pre|text)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fastest and simplest pattern: `\[\[\S+\s+\K{.*}` ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F0jWEg/2))

Explanation:

```
\[\[  #Match 2 opening square brackets
\S+   #Match 1 or more non-white-space characters
\s+   #Match 1 or more white-space characters
\K    #Start the fullstring match from this point (avoiding capture group)
{.*}  #Greedily match 0 or more non-line-terminating characters wrapped in curly brackets
```

*The curly brackets do not need to be escaped in my pattern because they are not mistaken for quantifiers.

Given the input value in my code to follow (`$in`), my pattern takes just **33** steps.  Tim's pattern takes **116** steps and uses a capture group which makes `preg_match_all()`'s output array twice as big.  inarilo's pattern takes **125** steps and uses a capture group.

If anyone particularly wants to have a capture group, this can be used: `/\[\[\S+\s+({.*})/`  costing just **36** steps.

Code ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bca78e095ab13943837bd7bca657c4c0b4ea5ad1)):

```
$in='dummy json: {json here: "asdas"}
[[table
  {json here: "asd{as}"}
]]
[[pre 
  {json here: "asdasx"}
]]
[[text {json here: "red"} ]]';

echo implode('<br>',(preg_match_all('/\[\[\S+\s+\K{.*}/',$in,$out)?$out[0]:[]));
```

Output:

```
{json here: "asd{as}"}<br>{json here: "asdasx"}<br>{json here: "red"}
```

Comment: sorry, maybe my title confuse you. but what I want is, get JSON in within certain string. If I use that, I will ended up take any json string.

Comment: I want get JSON in within certain string.

Comment: nah, it's ok mate. Someone already give me answer. thanks for your advice anyway.

Comment: @LShaf You have chosen a less refined solution.  Did you just want it to be imploded with `<br>`?  That wasn't clear in your question.  My answer is more efficient than the currently accepted one.

Comment: No, but I think his pattern just what I'm looking for.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fe312dc8f8d8d716d41690b495859e109551f1e your pattern ended up take up all json.

Comment: @LShaf My new pattern/method far outperforms the currently accepted answer.

Comment: okay mate, I just found a problem on your pattern. try this json `{sample: "hello {world}!!!"}`. Btw thanks for you answer but I still keep my decision.

Comment: @LShaf You should clarify your question, so I don't have to keep editing.  Your question is not clear.  I will edit my answer until it is correct.

Comment: New pattern: `\[\[\S+\s+\K{.*}` 33 steps.  Still more than 3x faster than the accepted answer.

Comment: @LShaf I have updated my answer.  This is the best answer on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
#^\[\[(?:table|pre|text)\s+(\{.*?\})\s+\]\]$#m
```

Removed the global modifier since you are using preg_match_all.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work:

```
(\[\[[(table|pre|text) ]*[\n ].*)({.*})
```

https://regex101.com/r/Yv67gb/1

This narrow down the sample to start with `[[table` or `[[pre` or `[[text`  and then start the json with `{` which ends with `}` containing and text in between.

Group 2 will be our result.

```
{json here: "asdas"}
{json here: "asdasx"}
{json here: "red"}
```

Comment: This pattern now fails given the OP's sample input change (stating in comments that the json value can include nested curly brackets.  https://regex101.com/r/F0jWEg/3